# Bing Maps address look up

Tags: xml, vb.net, bing-maps, bing, bing-api

I have currently set a basic Bing maps within my program using XML and VB, currently the user can simply zoom into any part of the map but I would like them to be able to type in an address into a textbox then automatically be take them to it with the click of a button, I understand this uses geo-coding, I was wondering if there was any articles I could read step by step as I don't no which references to add or where to start really.

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the Bing Maps REST Location API for geocoding. Here are some useful resources:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701711.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819168.aspx

http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2013/02/14/bing-maps-rest-service-tips-tricks/